# Input Validation for a String in C

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to make a loop that does not stop until the user inputs a string. For ex. if the user inputs a number or a letter it will say `Invalid input` until the user enters a string.

But for some strange reason, when I run my code and I input a string, the program continues to loop the block of code. [Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjBp5.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[100];
    char letter[100];

  lt:
    printf("\033[0;33m");
    printf("\nEnter your Name:\ni.e. Miguel\n");
    printf("\033[0m");
    scanf("%s", name);
    if (name != letter) {
       printf("\033[0;31m");
       printf("Invalid input");
       printf("\033[0m");
       goto lt;
    }
    return0;
}
```

I've tried the `goto` function to loop the code but seems like that isn't working.

Comment: At least this statement if (name != letter){ does not make sense.

Comment: In C please do not attempt to compare or test a string with `==`. The `name` will **never** be equal to `letter`. You need the input string's length to be more than `1`, and it cannot have every character as `isdigit().`

Comment: @868miig And this identifier return0 also is invalid.

Comment: @Moscow i made a mistake and left out the space between the return and 0

Comment: How does a letter (or for that matter a number) make an invalid string?  What is your definition of a "string"?

Comment: @WeatherVane ok thank you..i'll let you know if it works

Comment: @SteveSummit by the problem definition, I suppose.

Comment: You never put anything into `letter`. Why are you trying to compare the user's input with it?

Comment: @SteveSummit as you can see i declared both "letter" and "name" as a char which (when the user inputs data) it will accept the data as a string not a number

Comment: A string is any sequence of characters. Letters and digits are both characters. `"1234"` is a string containing 4 digits.

Comment: @Barmar I didnt do that because i wanted the user to enter his/her name and if its not a string it will loop

Comment: The characters that make up some representation of a number (_e.g._ a value written in base 10) _ARE_ a string. Check your terminology, because it matters. A string in C is just a bunch of characters, terminated by the NUL byte. If you want to make the input invalid in some cases, you must define that. For instance, checking if there are no actual letters in the string. It's up to you. I'm sure there are names out there which contain digits.

Comment: If you want it to be letters, why do you say "if the user inputs a number or a letter" that is't invalid? Do you mean it can't be just ONE letter?

Comment: @Barmar no because there is no such thing as a one lettered name

Comment: You didn't do what? Do you think that naming the variable "letter" is enough for the computer to understand that `if (name != letter)` means to check if the name has non-letter characters in it?

Comment: If you want to know the length of `name`, use `strlen(name)` and test that this is more than 1.

Comment: Tell that to the actor A Martinez.

Comment: Aside: the [BBC reported](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems) *When **Jennifer Null** tries to buy a plane ticket, she gets an error message on most websites. The site will say she has left the surname field blank and ask her to try again.*

Comment: Bottom line: You need to (1) read the user's input as a string (which you're basically already doing) and then (2) validate that the string typed by the user is acceptable.  You'll do that by some combination of (2a) checking whether it contains certain characters, (2b) making sure it does *not* contain certian other characters and (2c) checking its length.  It sounds like your requirements are 2a: don't care, 2b: no digits, and 2c: greater than 1 character (although I personally disagree with this).

Comment: But your existing test `if (name != letter)` doesn't come close to doing 2a, 2b, or 2c.  (The `letter` array is uninitialized, and anyway you can't meaningfully compare arrays like that.  Compared like that, any two arrays are always unequal — no matter what they contain — which I guess explains why you say your code always loops forever.)

Comment: @WeatherVane Imagine if the fellow had married one of the Pointer sisters and she took up a hyphenated name.... `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Uninitialized variables:

```
char letter[100];
```

`letter` is used uninitialized in your code. It's contents are indeterminate. Variables declared with automatic storage aren't implicitly initialised to 0.

### Comparing strings:

```
if (name != letter)
```

This only compares the pointer addresses (and I believe it invokes undefined behavior), not the contents of the what those pointers point to.

The C standard library provides a function `strcmp` that compares two strings.

*Note:* It's declared in `string.h`.

### Buffer overflow vulnerability:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

is similar to using `gets` (in terms of limiting input). `scanf` will happily continue to read from `stdin` until it sees a whitespace, ignore everything to the right hand side of the whitespace, (which leads to more problems down the road) and potentially overflow the buffer.

You could use a field width to limit input:

```
scanf("%99s", name);
```

Or even better, use `fgets`.

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

It will read at most `n - 1` characters and null-terminate the string.

*Side-note:* `fgets` will store the `\n` character in the buffer, which might not be what you want. Here's one way to remove it¹:

```
name[strcspn(name, "\n\r")] = '\0';
```

### `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions:

Ignoring the return value of `scanf` gainsays the 6th commandment of  Henry Spencer's *"The Ten Commandments for C Programmers"*:

> If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of
> difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the
> checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing
> fingers, for if thou thinkest ``it cannot happen to me'', the gods
> shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance.

```
if (scanf("%99s", name) != 1) {
   handle the error here..
}
```

### Using `goto`:

While that is a legal use, it's discouraged. `goto` should not be used for such purposes.

Instead, as @SimonGoater suggested, use a `while` loop.

---

> if the user inputs a number or a letter it will say Invalid input
> until the user enters a string.

So the requirements are:

1. Names should be greater than 1 character.
2. Names shouldn't have any numbers in them. (But my friends have names with numbers, and even special characters. :-( )

*Note:*

- You can't have a string with one `char`, unless that `char` is a null-byte.

*Possible Solutions:*

- As `strlen` doesn't include the null-terminator, we can use it to calculate the length of the string, and if it equals 1, handle the error accordingly.
- Iterate through the buffer character by character, and if you find a number or a special character, handle the error accordingly.

[1] You might want to give this a read for more:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67608

Comment: Might want to mention about `fgets()` reading and saving the `'\n'`.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char name[100];
char letter[100]="amir";

lt:
printf("\033[0;33m");
printf("\nEnter your Name:\ni.e. Miguel\n");
printf("\033[0m \n");
scanf("%s",name);
if(strcmp(name, letter) != 0){
   printf("\033[0;31m");
   printf("Invalid input");
   printf("\033[0m");
   goto lt;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here i use string header file and call strcmp(str1, str2) to compare two results if compare successful then it return 0

Comment: While this is clearly a beginner's exercise, it should be noted that for anything serious, scanf should not be used to get data from users as it can result in a buffer overflow. Also, the use of 'goto' is generally discouraged. You can use while(1) to loop until a break.

Comment: The OP evidently wanted to accept names that were (a) greater than 1 character long and (b) did not contain digits.  (This was kinda strange, but anyway.)  Here you accept only the single name "amir".  I don't see how this is relevant.